# Low perfomance system sync with large data?

Tags: backup, sync, ubuntu-16.04

I am standing in front of the following problem. I have two servers. They can connect to each other via ssh with pubkey files. They should backup each other (in my specific case a nextcloud data folder). Apart from the inital backup (each server ~500GB of data) I would like to sync the two servers. I know that this can be achived with rsync and cron.

Problem is here: The usage time of the two servers is very different (so no regullary intervall with cron possible). So because of low performance I cannot sync with rsync and provide a full functioning sync and share solution at the same time. If I do so, both servers are crashing.

How can I solve this problem? Shuting down for the time of the backup is not accepted because then my sponsors would not be very pleased.

Thanks for sensible reactions.

System: Raspbian 8 (Jessie) and Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

P.S.: If additional info is needed I provide it with pleasure!

Comment: Where are you syncing the data? Between the 2 servers? If it's purely a backup sync, I'd suggest getting a 3rd server they can both back up to. Do both servers provide the same service? I.e are they bring a nextcloud host, hosting the same data?

Comment: Third server is due to my pocket money not affordable. Also my parents are saying my rasperry is already eating to much power. I would like to sync between the servers. Both have nextcloud, yes. They are hosting two different nextcloud services and it should be kept this way.

Comment: Thanks! That's makes more sense. You should probably show them some stats on raspberry pi power consumption if they are concerned with them using too much power.. anyway. How much change in data happens on a daily basis in each nextcloud install? After the initial sync, then keeping them in sync shouldn't be much processing power to do so, unless of course there is a high amount of data change. You could do an rsync more often, so it syncs smaller amounts more regularly

Comment: I am struggling to understand the exact usage scenario - particularly how rsync and nextcloud are meant to interplay.   A way to get consistent backups would be to use LVM block devices, then take a snapshot of the block device and mirror that.   This will slow performance of the server, but provide a consistent point in time snapshot which can be mirrored - which I expect will prevent crashing.

Comment: I have two servers, being hosted on two diffrent places. The dailiy amount can change between a few MB to ~ 5 GB (100 MB/s down, 10 MB/s up; other Server 50 MB/s, down 5 MB/s up). With the power my parents are beginning to understand.

Comment: Are both devices always-on?

Comment: Problem would be: rsync syncs data, nextcloud likes to sync the data. Then the file would be locked. Am I right? Then there should be a crash and so there could be file damage and that's the last thing I want.

Comment: Yes both are always online

Comment: You should not be mixing rsync with nextcloud - ie you should not be trying to rsync 2 devices which are kept in sync by Nexcloud.   Why would you not simply rely on Nextcloud to perform the replication?   Another - possibly more radical - approach which might solve your problem (Which, btw, I still don't understand) might be to use gluster to provide georeplication.

Comment: Nextcloud recommends backing up itself via rsync. Also there is no intervall option for syncing built into nextcloud.